# Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `ForestGreen'

Tags: color, incompatibility, package-options

I am using the following packages in my files Latex sources:

```
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}

\newcommand{\ricardo}[1]{\colorbox{ForestGreen}{\color{white}\textsf{\textbf{Ricardo}}} \textcolor{ForestGreen}{#1}}
```

And to mark my notes in the text, I use the command:

```
\ricardo{text....}
```

How should I do to make Latex display my notes correctly?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The `xcolor` package is an extension of the `color` package, so I don't understand why you loaded the `color` package twice along with the `xcolor` package. Moreover, according to page 7 of the `xcolor` [documentation](http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf) `usenames` is obsolete. I cleaned up the code to this:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\newcommand{\ricardo}[1]{\colorbox{ForestGreen}{\color{white}   \textsf{\textbf{Ricardo}}} \textcolor{ForestGreen}{#1}}
\begin{document}
\ricardo{This should work.}
\end{document}
```

and the resulting output compiles without a problem:

[image]

Comment: Thank​ you so much for your help @DJP, now it's all working!

Comment: Given that `usenames' is obsolete, maybe this (\documentclass[usenames,dvipsnames]{beamer}
) should be changed at https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors#The_68_standard_colors_known_to_dvips ?

Comment: Indeed, in the documentation, http://mirror.utexas.edu/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/xcolor/xcolor.pdf, to use additional color like the one you wanna use, you have to add this option when you load the xcolor package. Check out the section 
2.4.2 Additional sets of colors in the document.
Simply put, to use it properly, you just need this line when load xcolor package:
`\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}`

Answer (score 11):

sorry I can't comment as I'm just a noob and I need reputation. I tried out the command in my document and it works perfect. Check the image below.

[image]

In my beamer, I had declared something like `\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}` while the document that I use based on tufte declares `\usepackage{xcolor}` in the .sty file.

Could you try renaming the third line of the code into `\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}` ?

Comment: Hello @crypto, I am using `\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}` I modified the third from `\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{color}` to `\usepackage{xcolor}`, as your suggestion, 
but I keep getting the same error: `Package xcolor Error: Undefined color ForestGreen`.

Comment: Just a small question. Could you try `\usepackage[usenames, dvipsnames]{xcolor}`? I don't happen to have an IEEEtran tex file to try it out. Have you installed the package xcolor?

Comment: You're welcome. Thank​ you so much for your help @crypto!

Answer (score 6):

A more general solution may simply be to define the color explicitly.

```
\definecolor{ForestGreen}{RGB}{34,139,34}
```