# Option clash with RMarkdown and beamer

Tags: r, knitr, pandoc, markdown, option-clash

I work across two separate Mac computers, a Macbook Pro at work, and a Macbook Air at home. Both macs are running identical operating systems. I am writing in RMarkdown, using `knitr` to compile `beamer` slides.

One machine runs perfectly, but the other generates a conflict with the `xcolor` package.

```
! Package xcolor Error: Undefined color `Maroon'.
```

This error has been reported elsewhere, with the primary solution to include the following line in a LaTeX document:

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}
```

Unfortunately, this is not possible when working from markdown. Even if it was possible, this would not explain why the document is compiling perfectly on one machine, but not on the other.

The session info (`sessionInfo()`) from RStudio is identical for both machines. The version info acquired from `$ latex -v` is also identical.

The RStudio session info is as follows:

```
R version 3.5.1 (2018-07-02)
Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin15.6.0 (64-bit)
Running under: macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Matrix products: default
BLAS: /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/libBLAS.dylib
LAPACK: /Library/Frameworks/R.framework/Versions/3.5/Resources/lib/libRlapack.dylib

locale:
    [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8

attached base packages:
    [1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
    [1] compiler_3.5.1  backports_1.1.2 magrittr_1.5    rprojroot_1.3-2
[5] htmltools_0.3.6 tools_3.5.1     yaml_2.2.0      Rcpp_0.12.18   
[9] stringi_1.2.4   rmarkdown_1.10  knitr_1.20      stringr_1.3.1  
[13] digest_0.6.15   evaluate_0.11
```

While the `latex -v` info is also identical and reads as follows:

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018)
kpathsea version 6.3.0
Copyright 2018 Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
There is NO warranty.  Redistribution of this software is
covered by the terms of both the pdfTeX copyright and
the Lesser GNU General Public License.
For more information about these matters, see the file
named COPYING and the pdfTeX source.
Primary author of pdfTeX: Han The Thanh (pdfTeX) et al.
Compiled with libpng 1.6.34; using libpng 1.6.34
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with xpdf version 4.00
```

I have also copied the full RStudio library section across the two machines, which effectively rules the RStudio environment out as a source of the problem.

A basic example of a slide deck that fails on one but not the other is as follows. This code should be saved as an *.Rmd file, and will require the `bookdown` package to be pre-installed.

````
---
title: 'Test slide deck'
author: "Rob Smith"
date: "Updated `r format(Sys.time(), '%B %d, %Y')`"
output:
  beamer_presentation:
    colortheme: seahorse
    fonttheme: serif
    slide_level: 3
    theme: Berkeley
  bookdown::gitbook:
    config:
      toc:
        collapse: section
    self.contained: yes
    split_by: none
  pdf_document: default
header-includes:
- \usepackage{tikz}
- \usepackage{pgfplots}
- \usepackage{fontawesome5}
- \usepackage{academicons}
urlcolor: red
---


```{r setup, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE)
```

# Test slide deck for code
## Section 1
### Slide 1
#### Box on slide 1

This is just a test file to demonstrate the problem with `xcolor`.
````

If possible I would like to identify all possible points of difference in the two TeX installations.

Is there by any chance a simple way to do this, either from the console in RStudio, or from the terminal in OSX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se. Can edit your question to add a small `.Rmd` file that will produce the problem for you on the machine that doesn't work?

Comment: Thanks for adding the code. This code produces the same error? I don't see any place in which the colour 'Maroon' is used.

Comment: @AlanMunn, It does indeed, according to other posts, the error appears to be generated in the links of the `Beamer` template. The template I believe calls the `xcolor` package from TeX. The `xcolor` question appears to have been addressed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/288915/package-xcolor-error-undefined-color-forestgreen) for the LaTeX environment. Unfortunately my knowledge of how pandoc works is fairly limited. I am just hoping that if I find the difference between the two installations I will be able to point to the actual culprit.

Comment: Unfortunately this compiles without error for me.  Try adding `knitr::opts_knit$set(latex.options.color = "dvipsnames,svgnames,x11names")` Does this change anything?

Comment: Still no luck, unfortunately. There must be something faulty with this installation, although it is a fresh installation of TeX 2018 distribution on both machines, which makes the difference seem strange.

Comment: I suspect the difference is in `pandoc` or `knitr` not MacTeX.

Comment: Try adding `classoption: color=dvipsnames,x11names,svgnames` before the `output:` line.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion that it might be `pandoc`! after you mentioned that, I realised that I had installed a `homebrew` version of `pandoc` on the Macbook Pro at a recent workshop. after running `$ brew install pandoc` the `xcolor` error has disappeared and the all of the files are compiling perfectly. Possibly a word of warning to anyone that is currently relying on the native `pandoc` installation that comes with RStudio. Unfortunately, because it is now working on both machines, I cannot check if your last suggestion would have worked, but that you very much for the help!

Comment: It actually would be helpful to add that as an answer. I have a `homebrew` install of `pandoc` too, which is obviously why I couldn't reproduce the error either.  Glad you got it solved.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @AlanMunn I stumbled across a solution to the problem.

Both machines are essentially set up identically, including:
OSX version (MacOS High Sierra, version 10.13.6 (17G65))
Rstudio version (1.1.456)
R version (3.5.1) (with native `pandoc` installation)
Tex live Distribution (2018)

After @AlanMunn 's comment I realised that at a recent workshop I installed `homebrew` version of `pandoc`, with the command:

```
$ brew install pandoc
```

After installing this, the `xcolor` package error disappeared and the documents compile perfectly on both machines. It would appear that the `homebrew` distribution is free of the problem caused by the native `RStudio` version.